# How can 1 carry-on suitcase be tied to 1 checked suitcase, to enable 1 hand to pull both?

Tags: luggage, tips-and-tricks, hand-luggage

Instead of pulling 1 carry-on  (e.g. the following 55 cm Spinner by Samsonite) and 1 full-size checked (30") suitcase separately, one with each hand, how can the carry-on be attached or fastened to the checked suitcase, to facilitate pulling both  with one hand and freeing the other hand?

[image]
One possibility is to purchase [Luggage Sets](https://www.google.com/search?q=pilot+luggage+sets&safe=off&biw=1088&bih=508&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNpMHRkJXPAhVh4oMKHSIbCzAQ_AUIBigB#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=flight+attendant+luggage+bags&imgrc=_) used by flight crew, but I wish not to spend extra money to do this when I already possess many suitcases.

[image]

Comment: helpful suggestions in http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30807/travelling-with-2-check-in-bags

Comment: Why is the photo mirrored?

Comment: @simbaque What does 'mirrored' mean here?

Comment: @pnuts I did not notice it; I found this image online.

Comment: Actually the whole image is. If you zoom in you can see that the departure and arrival list have larger letters (presumably captials) on the right, and the sign hanging from the ceiling also on the right down the corridor also has letters that appear the wrong way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used nylon compression straps (similar to what you attach a sleeping bag to a backpack with).  I run the strap through the smaller suitcase's handle (but keep the handle retracted inside the suitcase), then loop the strap around the handle of the bigger suitcase.  I tighten the strap to snug up the bags and away I go.  This works for roller suitcases, as well as large roller duffel bags (though for really large duffels I had a second strap at the midpoint).

It is very easy to deal with for scanners or check in, just drop the big suitcase handle and the strap comes free, staying with the carry on bag.

Answer (score 5):

Manufacturers who specifically market to air crews, such as Travelpro, will often include the hook with the bag.  It is integrated into the product and detachable from a fixed mount.

That is likely what the Flight Attendant pictured above is using.*

You can also purchase similar devices that attach to the handle.  Here is an example: [Travelon Add A Bag Strap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00864IF4A)

You can find other similar products by searching on "luggage hook" or "luggage strap".

*I am aware the larger bag is not a Travelpro but this feature is not exclusive to them.